# HttpPost Create MVC

Tags: model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-3, http-post

I have the following three classes:

```
public class AModel { .. } 

public class BModel { 
.. 
public List A { get; set; } 
} 

public class CModel { 
.. 
public List B { get; set; } 
}
```

How can I get the data in List objects in the httpPost Create of CModel Controller?

with the editor templates:

```
// CModel
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.B) 
<p>
    <input type="submit" value="Create" />
</p>

// BModel
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.A) 
<p>
    <input type="submit" value="Create" />
</p>
```

it works fine with List but I cannot access to the List objects in the httpPost create method.

thks in advance,

bruno grandjean

Answer (score 0):

If you have something like this

```
public class AModel { .. } 

public class BModel { 
.. 
public List<A>  AList { get; set; } 
} 

public class CModel { 
.. 
public List<B> BList { get; set; } 
}
```

you should be able to do

```
CModel model;
var blist model.BList;

foreach(var b in blist)
{
    var alist = b.Alist;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thks a lot for replying to me so quickly. I finally found the solution, here is my classes definition:

```
public partial class ClasseAmodel
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string label { get; set; }
}
public partial class ClasseBmodel
{
    public List<ClasseAmodel> classeA { get; set; }
}
public partial class ClasseCmodel
{        
    public List<ClasseBmodel> classeB { get; set; }
}
```

My ClasseCmodel create view :

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" 
    type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" 
    type="text/javascript"></script>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Create</legend>
        @Html.EditorFor(Model => Model.classeB)
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Save" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}
```

My EditorTemplates :

```
@model MetaCrud.Models.ClasseAmodel

<p>
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.id)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.id)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.id)
</p>
<p>
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.label)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.label)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.label)
</p>

@model MetaCrud.Models.ClasseBmodel

<p>
       @Html.EditorFor(Model => Model.classeA)
</p>
```

My ClasseCmodelController create methods :

```
// GET: /ClasseCmodel/Create
public ActionResult Create()
{
    var model = new ClasseCmodel();
    classeB = new List<ClasseBmodel>();
    var b = new ClasseBmodel();
    b.classeA = new List<ClasseAmodel>();
    var a = new ClasseAmodel();
    a.id = 1;
    a.label = "1";
    b.classeA.Add(a);
    a = new ClasseAmodel();            
    a.id = 2;
    a.label = "2";
    b.classeA.Add(a);
    classeB.Add(b);
    classeC = new List<ClasseCmodel>();

    return View(model);
} 

// POST: /ClasseCmodel/Create
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(ClasseCmodel model, FormCollection collection)
{
    return View(model);
}
```

In the last method I recover the whole set of my objects and in particularly the ClasseAmodel objects :

```
id = 1;
label = "1";
```

and

```
id = 2;
label = "2";
```

which was my main goal..
More interesting, I modified my ClasseCModel like that :

```
public partial class ClasseCmodel
{        
    public List<ClasseCmodel> classeC { get; set; }
}
```

So as to build a recursive List. I created an editor template for ClasseCmodel :

```
<p>
       @Html.EditorFor(Model => Model.classeC)
</p>
```

And just added :

```
@Html.EditorFor(Model => Model.classeC)
```

In the ClasseCmodel create view. 
I can add ClasseCmodel objects in the classeC list without pb and I get now a recursive view..